# DB2, group and sum by year where the year is a column value

Tags: sql, db2

I currently have a db2 query like so:

```
SELECT
         NUMBER ,
         YEAR(newDate),
         dollarAMT - CAST ( coupon * dollarAMT AS DECIMAL ( 12 , 2 ) ) AS TOTAL
        FROM ORDERING A
        LEFT JOIN table.clients CL ON CL . clientNUmber = A . clientNumber 
        WHERE
        newDate >= '2019-01-01'
         order by newDate asc;
```

and this gives values like this:

```
123   2019   100.00
123   2019   200.00
123   2020   500.00
123   2020   800.00  
123   2021   1000.00
```

I'm trying to get this result though:

```
Number   2019    2020      2021
123     300.00   1300.00  1000.00
```

How can I alter this in DB2 so that the years become column names and I group the sales by year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pivot your data, but DB2 doesn't support PIVOT , so you can do something like this:

```
select
    number,
    sum(case when YEAR(newDate) = 2019 then (dollarAMT - CAST ( coupon * dollarAMT AS DECIMAL ( 12 , 2 ) ) ) end) as 2019,
    sum(case when YEAR(newDate) = 2020 then (dollarAMT - CAST ( coupon * dollarAMT AS DECIMAL ( 12 , 2 ) ) ) end) as 2020,
    sum(case when YEAR(newDate) = 2021 then (dollarAMT - CAST ( coupon * dollarAMT AS DECIMAL ( 12 , 2 ) ) ) end) as 2021,
FROM ORDERING A
LEFT JOIN table.clients CL ON CL.clientNUmber = A.clientNumber
WHERE newDate >= '2019-01-01'
group by number 
order by number asc;
```

but if you can show them in rows instead of columns , it make the query much simpler and it doesn't need to be modified for each upcoming year:

```
SELECT
    NUMBER,
    YEAR(newDate),
    sum(dollarAMT - CAST (coupon * dollarAMT AS DECIMAL (12, 2))) AS TOTAL
FROM  ORDERING A
LEFT JOIN table.clients CL ON CL.clientNUmber = A.clientNumber
WHERE newDate >= '2019-01-01'
group by NUMBER, YEAR(newDate)
order by  NUMBER, YEAR(newDate) asc;
```